# Ideal number of partitions for Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, kafka-topic

I am currently working on a setup which has 6 `kafka-brokers`, Data is being pushed into my `topic` from two `producers` at a rate of about 4000 messages per second, I have 5 `Consumers` for this topic working as a group. What should be the ideal number of partitions of my `kafka topic`?

Please feel free to tell me if any change is required in `brokers/consumers/producers` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general more the partitions - more the throughput. However there are other considerations too like the limits of hardware you are running on, whether you are using compression etc. There is a good enough information from Confluent [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-choose-number-topics-partitions-kafka-cluster/) which provides you insight into rough calculation you can use to arrive at number of partitions.

> A rough formula for picking the number of partitions is based on
> throughput. You measure the throughout that you can achieve on a
> single partition for production (call it p) and consumption (call it
> c). Let’s say your target throughput is t. Then you need to have at
> least max(t/p, t/c) partitions. The per-partition throughput that one
> can achieve on the producer depends on configurations such as the
> batching size, compression codec, type of acknowledgement, replication
> factor, etc.

Moreover for consumer

> The consumer throughput is often application dependent since it
> corresponds to how fast the consumer logic can process each message

So the best way is to measure and benchmark for your own use case